# React Native 'Termination Reason: DYLD 1 Library missing' issue

Tags: ios, react-native, visual-studio-code, react-hooks, cross-platform

During the building of react native project. The app launched on the simulator, but after that getting a issue like this 'Termination Reason: DYLD 1 Library missing'
also attached the screenshot for the issue.[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Happened with me when I was working on react-native 0.70.0. 

Follow these steps to fix that:

1. Open XCode. Select Your Project > Your App from `Targets` > `Build Phases` > `Link Binary With Libraries` > Click on the `+` symbol and add the following:

- hermes.xcframework
- React-hermes (libReact-hermes.a)

2. Click on `Product` > `Clean Build Folder`
3. Now Build your Folder again.

Your App should work fine now.

Comment: Thanks Dibyajyoti. This worked for me. It should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after updating Xcode to the latest version. All I had to do is to delete the `Pods` folder and install pods again (by running `pod install` from the `ios` folder).

Alternatively, you can run this command from the `ios` directory:

```
pod cache clean --all && pod deintegrate && pod install --repo-update
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the cocoapads to 1.14.3 resolved the issue for me.

```
brew upgrade cocoapods
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```